# vb.net Actualizar datatable a MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Buenos días:

En este momento estoy desarrollando una pequeña app en VS.2015 (VB), tengo dos bases de datos, la primera en MySQL y la segunda en Ms-SQL, ambas tienen la misma estructura, primero hago un select y traigo los datos de una tabla de cada base de datos a un dataset y un datatable, luego hago una breve comparación entre los datatable, y por último devuelvo la taba final hacia ambas bases de datos, cuando lo hago hacia MS-SQL no tengo problema y actualiza, pero cuando lo hago hacia MySQL no actualiza, tampoco me arroja error o excepción. El código que estoy utilizando es:

```
Dim condicion As String = ""
Dim Tabla As String = "Horarios"
'Objects MySql'
Dim conMySql As MySqlConnection
Dim cmdMySql As MySqlCommand
Dim comBMySql As MySqlCommandBuilder
Dim daMySql As MySqlDataAdapter

'Objects Sql'
Dim conSql As SqlConnection
Dim cmdSql As SqlCommand
Dim comSql As SqlCommandBuilder
Dim daSql As SqlDataAdapter

conSql = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.MsSql.ToString)
cmdSql = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & Tabla & IIf(Condicion <> "", " WHERE " & Condicion, ""), conSql)
daSql = New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSql)
conSql.Open()
cmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery()
daSql.Fill(dsg, Tabla & "1")
conSql.Close()

conMySql = New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.MySqlLocal.ToString)
cmdMySql = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & Tabla & IIf(Condicion <> "", " WHERE " & Condicion.Replace("GETDATE", "CURDATE"), ""), conMySql)
daMySql = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmdMySql)
conMySql.Open()
cmdMySql.ExecuteNonQuery()
daMySql.Fill(dsg, Tabla)
conMySql.Close()

Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = dsg.Tables(Tabla)
Form1.DataGridView2.DataSource = dsg.Tables(Tabla & "1")

dsg.Tables(Tabla).Merge(dsg.Tables(Tabla & "1"))

comBMySql = New MySqlCommandBuilder(daMySql)

Dim upcmdmysql As MySqlCommand
upcmdmysql = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE horarios SET idhorario = ?idhorario, NombreHora = ?NombreHora, Entrada1 = ?Entrada1, Salida1 = ?Salida1, Entrada2 = ?Entrada2, Salida2 = ?Salida2, Observacion = ?Observacion", conMySql)

For Each columna In dsg.Tables(Tabla).Columns
    upcmdmysql.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?" & columna.ToString, columna.GetType))
    upcmdmysql.Parameters("?" & columna.ToString).SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original
    upcmdmysql.Parameters("?" & columna.ToString).SourceColumn = columna.ToString
Next

daMySql.UpdateCommand = upcmdmysql
daMySql.Update(dsg.Tables(Tabla))
```

Answer (score 0):

quizás mi respuesta sea corta y no profunda pero creo que el error lo estás cometiendo en esta parte:

```
comBMySql = New MySqlCommandBuilder(daMySql)

Dim upcmdmysql As MySqlCommand
upcmdmysql = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE horarios SET idhorario = ?idhorario, NombreHora = ?NombreHora, Entrada1 = ?Entrada1, Salida1 = ?Salida1, Entrada2 = ?Entrada2, Salida2 = ?Salida2, Observacion = ?Observacion", conMySql)

For Each columna In dsg.Tables(Tabla).Columns
    upcmdmysql.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?" & columna.ToString, columna.GetType))
    upcmdmysql.Parameters("?" & columna.ToString).SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original
    upcmdmysql.Parameters("?" & columna.ToString).SourceColumn = columna.ToString
Next

daMySql.UpdateCommand = upcmdmysql
daMySql.Update(dsg.Tables(Tabla))
```

A mi también me sucedió lo mismo y terminé, luego de muchisimo buscar, utilizando el comando **UPDATE** solo pasándole el parámetro de la Tabla. Eso significa que cuando tu modificas la tabla en memoria que llenaste con tu anterior Fill, luego solo haces Update y eso ejecuta automáticamente el Update en la Base.

En resumen: modifica la DataTable que llenas con daMySql.Fill(dsg, Tabla) directamente y luego ejecuta daMySql.Update(dsg.Tables(Tabla)).

Inténtalo así.

EDIT:

Te dejo la parte de código donde lleno el DataTable. Esto también es muy importante ya que en un principio a mi tampoco me funcionó y con esto si logré hacerlo funcionar.

```
Try
            If Not cEJECUTAR.State = ConnectionState.Open Then cEJECUTAR.Open()
            dgABMSist.Columns.Clear()
            DT = New DataTable
            Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
            stm = "SELECT * FROM " & Tabla & ";"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = stm
            cmd.Connection = cEJECUTAR
            Adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            cb = New MySqlCommandBuilder(Adapter)
            Adapter.Fill(DT)
            With dgABMSist
                .AutoGenerateColumns = True
                .DataSource = DT
            End With
            cmd.Dispose()
            cmd = Nothing
            cEJECUTAR.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            tsInfoSQL.Text = "Error en la consulta: " & Mid(ex.Message, 1, 100)
            tsEstado.Image = LCDR.My.Resources.Resources.ico_rechazado
        End Try
```

Comment: Lo intentaré y te cuento, muchas gracias

Comment: Miguel, ¿Cómo te ha ido con esto? Podrías colocar si mi respuesta fue de tu ayuda ^^

Comment: Hola, lo intenté pero no funcionó, tuve que generar los comandos individualmente, comparar a través de data tables y luego con instrucciones por cada row

Comment: Entonces te faltaría intentar con verificar de que modo llenas en principio el DataTable. A mi me pasó lo mismo que a vos: en un principio el código del ".Update" estaba bien pero no funcionaba y luego de modificar y arreglar como llenaba el DataTable funcionó. Fijate que lo edité en mi respuesta.